# При подключении файла, с помощью require_once, вместо использования одной переменной, выполнялся код файла

Tags: php, сессия, header, include, required

Код файла в котором вызывается файл  (index.php) :

```
<?php
//require_once 'auth/signin.php'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Discusser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="header__title">Discussion club</div>
            <nav>
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
if($_SESSION['user'])
{
    echo '<a class="button header__button--enter" href="office.html">Личный кабинет</a> ';
}else{
            echo '<a class="button header__button--enter" href="../login.php">Войти</a> ' .
                '<a class="button header__button--reg" href="../register.php">Регистрация</a>';
}
?>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="hello">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hello__inner">
                    <h1>Приветствуем!</h1>
                    <div class="hello__text">text</div>
                    <a class="button hello__button" href="#">Начать</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Код файла, который вызывается (signin.php) :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$check_user = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password' AND `verified`=1");
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_user);
//var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($check_user));
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_user) > 0)
{
$_SESSION['user'] = [
    "id" => $user['id'],
    "login" => $user['login'],
    "email" => $user['email'],
];
header('Location: ../index.php');
//var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['message']='Неправильный логин или пароль';
    header('Location: ../login.php');
}
```

По какой-то причине, при открытии index.php, идет переход на login.php с помощью header из signin.php. Пытался включать\отключать сессию, менять require\include, но все равно идет переход на файл. Так же непонятно почему в index.php отказывается пустая суперглобальная переменная $_SESSION. Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: `header('Location: ../login.php');`

Comment: так, у меня такая строчка уже есть...

Comment: вот она и отправляет на login. Непонятно, про что вопрос тогда

Comment: то есть при подключении файла signin.php, выполняется header в нем? А как добавить файл без выполнения этой функции, просто что бы переменную вытянуть?

Comment: у вас переменная появляется  в результате выполнения кода

Comment: то есть при добавлении файла, полностью выполняется его код?